# Is it possible to compile a program written in Python?

Tags: python, compilation

I am new to the Python programming language. I was wondering if it is possible to compile a program to written in Python.

Is it possible to convert Python scripts to some lower level programming languages which then can be compiled to binary code?

A developer who is considering to code in Python might want to keep the possibility open to be able to go for binary distribution later.

Comment: you don't actually "compile" a python script. you run it with the Python interpreter.

Comment: @ghostdog74 - Yes, but Python _can_ be compiled.

Comment: @andrew, yes i do know Python can be compiled. This guy is new to Python, so i take it that he meant compiling as what you do with C for example, not more advanced stuff like py2exe or pyc files...

Comment: I've tried Python years ago, so my knowledge can be wrong or outdated. Python programs are not supposed to be turned into an exe file. Programs in Pythons are usually shipped with the language itself so people first install Python to run it. 4 Years ago I've found a way to turn it into an exe file. It was non-trivial and I hope that somebody was sensible enough to add an easier way to turn the program into exe file into the language.

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/61899114/3404480

Answer (score 65):

I think [Compiling Python Code](http://web.archive.org/web/20201111220256/http://effbot.org/zone/python-compile.htm) would be a good place to start:

> Python source code is automatically
> compiled into Python byte code by the
> CPython interpreter. Compiled code is
> usually stored in PYC (or PYO) files,
> and is regenerated when the source is
> updated, or when otherwise necessary.
>
> To distribute a program to people who
> already have Python installed, you can
> ship either the PY files or the PYC
> files. In recent versions, you can
> also create a ZIP archive containing
> PY or PYC files, and use a small
> “bootstrap script” to add that ZIP
> archive to the path.
>
> To “compile” a Python program into an
> executable, use a bundling tool, such
> as Gordon McMillan’s installer
> (alternative download)
> (cross-platform), Thomas Heller’s
> py2exe (Windows), Anthony Tuininga’s
> cx_Freeze (cross-platform), or Bob
> Ippolito’s py2app (Mac). These tools
> puts your modules and data files in
> some kind of archive file, and creates
> an executable that automatically sets
> things up so that modules are imported
> from that archive. Some tools can
> embed the archive in the executable
> itself.

Comment: "effbot.org on hiatus
effbot.org is taking a break. We’ll be back, in some form or another." the link doesn't work. idk

Comment: @CrazyVideoGamez, [page is available on Wayback](http://web.archive.org/web/20201111220256/http://effbot.org/zone/python-compile.htm), I've submitted an edit.

Answer (score 36):

If you really want, you could always compile with [Cython](https://github.com/cython/cython). This will generate C code, which you can then compile with any C compiler such as GCC.

Comment: Cython is great. But unfortunately, cythonized code is too far from vanilla Python. There is a [Python → 11l → C++ transpiler](http://11l-lang.org/transpiler) which requires much less work.

Answer (score 31):

Python, as a dynamic language, cannot be "compiled" into machine code statically, like C or COBOL can. You'll always need an interpreter to execute the code, which, by definition in the language, is a dynamic operation.

You can "translate" source code in bytecode, which is just an intermediate process that the interpreter does to speed up the load of the code, It converts text files, with comments, blank spaces, words like 'if', 'def', 'in', etc in binary code, but the operations behind are exactly the same, in Python, not in machine code or any other language. This is what it's stored in .pyc files and it's also portable between architectures.

Probably what you need it's not "compile" the code (which it's not possible) but to "embed" an interpreter (in the right architecture) with the code to allow running the code without an external installation of the interpreter. To do that, you can use all those tools like py2exe or cx_Freeze.

Maybe I'm being a little pedantic on this :-P

Answer (score 17):

You dont have to compile it. the first you use it (import) it is compiled by the CPython interpreter. But if you really want to compile there are several options.

To compile to exe

- [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)
- [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/)
- [py2app](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html)

Or 2 compile just a specific *.py file, you can just use

```
import py_compile
py_compile.compile("yourpythoncode.py")
```

Comment: py2exe is especially good for this. I have used it plenty and am VERY happy with it. It even accommodates all your import statements and multiple modules/code files

Comment: Which is the best one in terms of compactness and efficiency of code, that is, performances?

Answer (score 7):

To avoid the redundancy, I won't repeat my answer here.

Please refer to my another answer [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607283/how-can-i-manually-generate-a-pyc-file-from-a-py-file/38426786#38426786). (note that answer only covers compiling to *python bytecode*.)

Comment: That answer only covers compiling to bytecode.

Comment: You are right @lucid_dreamer. Some people might hit this page just to know the same. Other solutions in this page is already addressing how to compile a python script into machine code.

Comment: I've +1 your answer, I think it's useful, but I've suggested an edit so that it's clear it's just for bytecode.

Comment: Thanks @lucid_dreamer

Answer (score 4):

python is an interpreted language, so you don't need to compile your scripts to make them run.  The easiest way to get one running is to navigate to it's folder in a terminal and execute "python somefile.py".  This depends on you having python installed from [the python site.](http://www.python.org/download/windows/)

You can compile python apps, but that is generally not something a new developer needs to do initially.  If that is what you're looking for, take a peek at [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/).  This will take your python script and package it up as an executable file like any program on your windows-based computer.  You can also compile individual files using python, as described in the "Compiling Python modules to byte code" section at [this site.](http://effbot.org/zone/python-compile.htm)

Answer (score -3):

python compile on the fly when you run it.

Run a .py file by(linux): python abc.py

Comment: Not quite - python is *interpreted* when you run it. Running a Python script still requires Python (and all required libraries) to be installed on your system. A *compiled* program (see: C++, Fortran) converts source into a binary, which you can distribute to others. They won't need `gcc` or any libraries your code depends on; it will be self-contained within the executable itself.