# how the bittorent is compiled to exe

Tags: python, executable

As all know bittorrent is written in python program. whenever i download and install the bittorrent.exe, I never found any file(like dll etc) associated in program files i mean whenever i go to c:\program files\bittorrent i found only single file called bittorrent.exe, i wonder how this program is compiled to exe , whereas whenever i want to build standalone python exe i use py2exe and i found the output consists of nearly 25mb, which consists of all library file included. 
Can anybody will tell me the detail structure how the bittorent  program is build into exe.

Comment: Bittorrent isn't program. It is the protocol and it can be implemented practically in any language you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to compile a program written in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957054/is-it-possible-to-compile-a-program-written-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually bittorrent is a protocol. The *original* program which implemented bittorrent may have been written in Python but that's not the case now.

A lot of them now are coded in compiled languages, Transmission being the one I'm most familiar with (comes with Ubuntu) - it uses gcc.

Comment: might not want to let on you are familiar with uTorrent! ;)

Answer (score 2):

You mean the, umm, "official" BitTorrent client from [bittorrent.com](http://bittorrent.com), right? I couldn't find the latest source code but older versions were built using py2exe (see [winsetup.py](http://google.de/codesearch/p?hl=en#I0cABDTB4TA/pub/FreeBSD/ports/distfiles/BitTorrent-4.26.0.tar.gz|AsXw4syKLdQ/BitTorrent-4.26.0/windows_installer/winsetup.py) of the client v4.26). I can't explain why your py2exe output is so huge, but the setup.py file included in the sources seems to exclude a lot of modules. Maybe you used the setup.py file that was intended for Linux/Unix.

If you didn't mean that client GUI, you should know that BitTorrent is actually just the protocol, and there exist multiple libraries and GUIs that implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.bittorrent.com/company/jobs. They are looking for C/C++ developers... not python.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the documentation for the BitTorrent client that you use. There are [several Python clients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_BitTorrent_clients#Interface_and_programming) and each one does things differently.