# How can I manually generate a .pyc file from a .py file

Tags: python

For some reason, I can not depend on Python's "import" statement to generate .pyc file automatically

Is there a way to implement a function as following?

```
def py_to_pyc(py_filepath, pyc_filepath):
    ...
```

Answer (score 333):

You can use `compileall` in the terminal. The following command will go recursively into sub directories and make pyc files for all the python files it finds. The [compileall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/compileall.html) module is part of the python standard library, so you don't need to install anything extra to use it. This works exactly the same way for python2 and python3.

```
python -m compileall .
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer --at least in my need to compile all *.py into *.pyc: recursively :)

Comment: Is it possible to distribute a PYC file containing all the libraries used? So users doesn't have to install them, just ran the PYC file, I know in java this is possible using a JARs are there any similar method for Python?

Comment: I heard also something about meta files in Python. This compileall also build some cache? If not, what is the command for that?? Since the end-users doesn't have write permission to the lib directory. And I want to speed up things here... PS. also take a look at the `-O` flag, for bytecode (.pyo file iso .pyc) compilation.

Comment: what about decompiling?

Comment: be careful with this command. I did accidentally do a `compileall` on my site-packages folder and it messed up everything

Comment: I'm using an Anaconda distribution of Python.  It's housed in a ProgramData subfolder, where I don't want to store my .py files.  How can I use this command to compile a specific folder?

Comment: I am working on Amazon AMI where `python3 -m compileall .` was just listing all the directories. I had to force it to compile by `python3 -m compileall . -f`

Comment: On shell, how would you specify the output file location ? I tried **python -m compileall test.py out_test.pyc** but that would fail. I could not find a solution online

Comment: @D.Snap, the most standard way on Linux (non-Debian distributions) is to build a custom RPM.  For Python, you can either make an RPM by having your SRPM the py files and the RPM ends up being the pyc.  Unless you have made a source distribution or binary distribution in Python.  Then the process is a little different.

Comment: Recursively: find /py_files_folders -name "*.py" -exec python -m compileall {} \;

Answer (score 77):

You can compile individual files(s) from the command line with:

```
python -m compileall <file_1>.py <file_n>.py
```

Answer (score 66):

It's been a while since I last used Python, but I believe you can use [`py_compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/py_compile.html#py_compile.compile):

```
import py_compile
py_compile.compile("file.py")
```

Comment: You probably want to include the second parameter, which determines the output file. Otherwise, it defaults to something like `__pycache__/file.cpython-32.pyc` and you get that as the return value.

Answer (score 62):

I found **several** ways to compile python scripts into bytecode

1. Using `py_compile` in terminal:

   ```
   python -m py_compile File1.py File2.py File3.py ...
   ```

   `-m` specifies the module(s) name to be compiled.

   Or, for interactive compilation of files

   ```
   python -m py_compile -
   File1.py
   File2.py
   File3.py
      .
      .
      .
   ```
2. Using `py_compile.compile`:

   ```
   import py_compile
   py_compile.compile('YourFileName.py')
   ```
3. Using `py_compile.main()`:

   It compiles several files at a time.

   ```
   import py_compile
   py_compile.main(['File1.py','File2.py','File3.py'])
   ```

   The list can grow as long as you wish. Alternatively, you can obviously pass a list of files in main or even file names in command line args.

   Or, if you pass `['-']` in main then it can compile files interactively.
4. Using `compileall.compile_dir()`:

   ```
   import compileall
   compileall.compile_dir(direname)
   ```

   It compiles every single Python file present in the supplied directory.
5. Using `compileall.compile_file()`:

   ```
   import compileall
   compileall.compile_file('YourFileName.py')
   ```

Take a look at the links below:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/py_compile.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/compileall.html

Comment: One small correction is that the module name you are loading is `py_compile` and `compileall` NOT `py_compile.py` or `compileall.py`. In other words, it should be `python3 -m py_compile PYTHON_FILENAME` or `python3 -m compileall PYTHON_FILES_DIRECTORY`.

Answer (score 19):

I would use [compileall](http://docs.python.org/library/compileall.html). It works nicely both from scripts and from the command line. It's a bit higher level module/tool than the already mentioned [py_compile](http://docs.python.org/library/py_compile.html) that it also uses internally.

Comment: `compileall` does not include logic to skip files for which the corresponding `.pyc` file is already up-to-date, does it?

Comment: @KyleStrand `compileall` does skip files that already have an up-to-date `.pyc` (tested with Python 2.7.11)

Comment: @Eponymous Interesting. Not sure why I thought otherwise. Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 19):

Normally the following command compilies a python project:

```
python -m compileall <project-name>
```

In Python2 it compiles all `.py` files to `.pyc` files in a project which contains packages as well as modules.

Whereas in Python3 it compiles all `.py` files to `__pycache__` folders in a project which contains packages as well as modules.

With browning from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53945327/3702377):

> You can enforce the same layout of `.pyc` files in the folders as in
> Python2 by using:
>
> `python3 -m compileall -b <pythonic-project-name>`
>
> The option `-b` triggers the output of `.pyc` files to their
> legacy-locations (i.e. the same as in Python2).

Answer (score 5):

To match the original question requirements (source path and destination path) the code should be like that:

```
import py_compile
py_compile.compile(py_filepath, pyc_filepath)
```

If the input code has errors then the *py_compile.PyCompileError* exception is raised.

Answer (score 1):

#### There are two ways to do this

1. Command line
2. Using python program

If you are using command line, use [`python -m compileall <argument>`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/compileall.html) to compile python code to python binary code.
Ex: `python -m compileall -x ./*`

***Or,***
You can use this code to compile your library into byte-code:

```py
import compileall
import os

lib_path = "your_lib_path"
build_path = "your-dest_path"

compileall.compile_dir(lib_path, force=True, legacy=True)

def moveToNewLocation(cu_path):
    for file in os.listdir(cu_path):
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(cu_path, file)):
            compile(os.path.join(cu_path, file))
        elif file.endswith(".pyc"):
            dest = os.path.join(build_path, cu_path ,file)
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dest), exist_ok=True)
            os.rename(os.path.join(cu_path, file), dest)

moveToNewLocation(lib_path)
```

look at [☞ docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/compileall.html) for detailed documentation

Answer (score 1):

1. create a new python file in the directory of the file.
2. type `import (the name of the file without the extension)`
3. run the file
4. open the directory, then find the **pycache** folder
5. inside should be your .pyc file