# How to convert a string into a pyc file without using a py file?

Tags: python-3.x, pyc

I have a string `print("hello")`. I want to directly store this as a .pyc file and execute it later. How can I do this?

Comment: Please have a look at this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5607315/1155650) for the [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5607283/1155650)

Comment: I am already aware of py_compile, which necessiates a .py file. I want to do the same without a .py file getting created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [py_compile.compile](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/py_compile.html#py_compile.compile) and its [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Lib/py_compile.py) to see how it is done.

Comment: I get an ImportError at "from py_compile import wrlong"

Comment: It is `wr_long`, I made a typo.

Comment: It does not recognise wr_long as well. Am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice you're using python 3. I edited the link to the sources.