# How to make a .pyc file from Python script

Tags: python, terminal, pyc

I know that when Python script is imported in other python script, then a .pyc script is created. Is there any other way to create .pyc file by using linux bash terminal?

Comment: can't do  $ python -c "import script" ?

Comment: [`python -m compileall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/compileall.html)

Comment: I think you should try to use 'zipfile' to make pyc.
It's so easy to make it.
You can use it to deploy your code by no src.

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61899114/3404480 it may help you in python3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the [`py_compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/py_compile.html#py_compile.main) module. Run it from command line (`-m` option):

> When this module is run as a script, the *main()* is used to compile all
>   the files named on the command line.

Example:

```
$ tree
.
└── script.py

0 directories, 1 file
$ python3 -mpy_compile script.py
$ tree
.
├── __pycache__
│   └── script.cpython-34.pyc
└── script.py

1 directory, 2 files
```

[`compileall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/compileall.html) provides similar functionality, to use it you'd do something like

```
$ python3 -m compileall ...
```

Where `...` *are files to compile or directories that contain source files, traversed recursively*.

---

Another option is to import the module:

```
$ tree
.
├── module.py
├── __pycache__
│   └── script.cpython-34.pyc
└── script.py

1 directory, 3 files
$ python3 -c 'import module'
$ tree
.
├── module.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── module.cpython-34.pyc
│   └── script.cpython-34.pyc
└── script.py

1 directory, 4 files
```

`-c 'import module'` is different from `-m module`, because the former won't execute the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block in *module.py*.

Answer (score 10):

Use the following command:

```
python -m compileall <your_script.py>
```

This will create `your_script.pyc` file in the same directory.

You can pass directory also as :

```
python -m compileall <directory>
```

This will create .pyc files for all .py files in the directory

Other way is to create another script as

```
import py_compile
py_compile.compile("your_script.py")
```

It also create the your_script.pyc file. You can take file name as command line argument