# Where can i find the pyc file?

Tags: python-3.x, compilation, pyc

The python3 version is Python 3.5.3 in my os.

```
mkdir  workspace
cd workspace
vim  print.py
print("i am learning")
```

Saved and exit.

```
python3 print.py
i am learning
```

As far as i knew, python source file was parsed and compiled into pyc file when to execute it.

```
ls
print.py
```

There is no pyc file in workspace directory,where is the complied `print.py` file then?

```
sudo find  /  -name  ".pyc"
```

The find command still can't search `pyc` file such as  `print.pyc` .
`python3 -m compileall` can create the compiled file for `print.py` manually,where is the compiled file for `print.py` created by python itself?
Does python3 delete the `print.pyc` after executing `python3 print.py`?

Comment: It's normally created when you *import* the file. If you want to manually generate it, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5607283/3001761

Comment: `python3 -m compileall `can create the compiled file for print.py manually,where is the compiled file for print.py created by python itself?

Comment: Does python3 delete the print.pyc after executing python3 print.py?

Comment: No, it just never saves it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is one big of a problem I ever had when I'm started to learn python few years back. Python is just like any other oop programming languages which does compilation before program execution. When python compiles its program, it creates the bite code which is you can see by standard library called `dis`.

```
import dis
print(dis.dis(your_program))
```

Sometimes (not always) python creates `.pyc` file for the running programs to improve the ***speed up the loading of import modules*** but not to improve the execution time. So hope you get intuition behind `.pyc`, furthermore `.pyc` only creates when your module is import by another module.

As an example, Imagine you have this `print.py` (Let's modify it shall we)

```
def return_print_statment(statement):
    print('Printed version: ', statement)
```

Suppose this module imported by another custom module called `views.py`. In `views.py` there is a `module_view` which will use the `return_print_statment`

```
from print import return_print_statment

def module_view():
    ...
    return_print_statment(output)
```

So in the compilation, since you have imported the `print.py` python will generate `print.pyc` file for it. In python 2.0 python will put the `.pyc` to right next to your program in the same folder, but in python3 instead of creating in the same folder python will create separate folder called `__pycache__` in the same directory to put these byte codes.

Answer (score 0):

python3 -m compileall .

To compile all .py files in your current directory.

http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-create-a-pyc-file.htm