# What is the best way to decompile and compile Python PYC to PY Then PY to PYC

Tags: python

I have a compiled python code with the `PYC` extension.
I'm trying to decompile it from `PYC` to `PY` then I've some changes I want to make it in `PY` then I want to compile the `PY` to `PYC` again without missing anything in the code that will cause the problem in running. THNQ

Comment: Maybe see this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287253

Comment: First part should be answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14808336/10306224
Second part is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22779209/10306224

Comment: I really did not have any idea about new upgrades of the python packages. so can you please give me a clear way to compile then compile the python code?

Comment: Can yo please tell me why I get this `Error: uncompyle6 requires Python 2.6-3.8` when I write this command `uncompyle6 -h`, I get the same error in both Python versions 2.7 or 3.7.

Comment: same problem than duhok