# Use .pyc for entire Python distribution and apps

Tags: python, binary, fips, pyc

I have a restriction on my embedded device to only contain python main distribution and apps to be .pyc, i.e. no source code .py files. Note this has nothing to do with protecting source code or hiding IP.

The requirement comes from a security standard (fips 140-3) that wants to keep all just in time compiled code to be in binary and not in source format. Any ideas ?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to ask

Comment: My question is basically whether I can just release a Python distribution and some apps in pyc format.

Comment: I don't know how to do it, but this answer could be a great start: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22779209/6110160