# How to compile a Python module to dll and call it in VBA

Tags: python, vba, dll

I want to create a user defined function written in Python. Then I want to compile it to a dll, and distribute it and call in EXCEL vba on another computer which doesn't have python installed.

For example, I want to create a function in Python:

def add(a,b):
   return a+b

Then, compile it and export it as a dll. On another computer without Python, I can to import this function in EXCEL vba and use it. How to do it?

Thanks,

Comment: See [Is it possible to compile a program written in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957054/is-it-possible-to-compile-a-program-written-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

in excel go to the vbe editor Tools>References browse your dll and add a reference, this will make available your dll functions in vba.

as per making it a dll, look what jb suggest here [How to compile a Python package to a dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859369/how-to-compile-a-python-package-to-a-dll) and follow the comments on that as well.

another option would be like stated here https://code.google.com/archive/p/shedskin/