# Make python program standalone executable under linux

Tags: python, linux, executable

How to make python program standalone executable under linux

I have done some research but I am not looking for a way to make a script and run the .py file like answered in this question. [What do I use on linux to make a python program executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304883/what-do-i-use-on-linux-to-make-a-python-program-executable)

I am looking to "complie" the .py to a standalone program so users in a linux environment like ubuntu can run it out of the box without installing python and the libraries I used because no root access. 
I found py2exe for windows. I would think there is a way to achieve this in linux?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1957054/6145303

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5458250/538418

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't pyinstaller compile under the OS you are using?

if you want a windows exe - use pyinstaller in windows environment...

For Linux, use pyinstaller in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Jython` to compile it to JVM. [Using the Jython compiler](http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/jythonc.html)

```
jythonc [options] [module]*
```

This would, however, require Java to be installed...

There are also a couple of other resources to compile Python. From [Compiling Python Code](http://effbot.org/zone/python-compile.htm), some cross-platform tools are

- [Gordon McMillan’s installer](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) (cross-platform)
- [Anthony Tuininga’s cx_Freeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/) (cross-platform)

but I do not know anything about those.