# convert python script file to binary in linux operating system

Tags: python, linux

How do i convert python script file to binary executable file in Linux operating system.

Ex scriptfile.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Hello, World"
```

How to covert scriptfile.py to binaray file "scriptfile"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency visit this may be this can help

Comment: Another good one with a top answer posting many references: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957054/is-it-possible-to-compile-a-program-written-in-python